# Sum total of table with two related tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm here with this (I'm sure it is) simple question I can't figure out how to solve.

I have this schema:

[image: schema]

With this data:

[image: person table]

[image: fruit table]

[image: cookie table]

My expected result is:

For "JOHN NASH":

```
PERSON_NAME | TOTAL_FRUIT | TOTAL COOKIE
----------------------------------------
JOHN NASH   |       10    |     38
```

For "OSCAR WILDE":

```
PERSON_NAME | TOTAL_FRUIT | TOTAL COOKIE
----------------------------------------
OSCAR WILDE |       28    |      0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure for the TOTAL_COOKIE of JOHN NASH the correct number is 38 and not 21?

Comment: Yes, 38 is the correct cookie total for JOHN NASH :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name, IFNULL(f.total, 0) AS total_fruit, IFNULL(c.total, 0) AS total_cookie
FROM person AS p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT person_idperson, SUM(cost) AS total
           FROM fruit
           GROUP BY person_idperson) AS f
ON p.idperson = f.person_idperson
LEFT JOIN (SELECT person_idperson, SUM(cost) AS total
           FROM cookie
           GROUP BY person_idperson) AS c
ON p.idperson = c.person_idperson
```

Comment: Thank you very much [Barmar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)! Your solution works perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT p.name AS PERSON_NAME, 
    IFNULL(SUM(f.cost),0) AS TOTAL_FRUIT, 
    IFNULL(SUM(c.cost),0) AS TOTAL_COOKIE
FROM person AS p
LEFT JOIN fruit as f
    ON p.idperson = f.person_idperson
LEFT JOIN cookie as c
    ON p.idperson = c.person_idperson
GROUP BY p.idperson
```

Comment: Returns 30 as TOTAL_FRUIT for JOHN NASH not 10

Comment: Yes, that's true. At first sight it seemed correct, but why it is wrong?

Comment: I don't testing it before ;) when try second join, the records repeated three times, and the sum returns 3*10 = 30